# cmd and bat behaving differently

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

EDIT:

After discussing the issue with a colleague, we think we know why the .bat runs differently than when typing line by line in cmd window. We think that the line `./venv/Scripts/activate.bat` activates a virtual environment in a shell different than where the rest of the code runs. I would need all of the code to run within the same shell from that line onwards. (FYI, I'm not sure if this makes sense as I'm relatively new to this.)

I am trying to create a virtual environment by running a bat file with the necessary commands to do so. When I run the lines from my .bat code by copy pasting them into the cmd window and running each individually, the code works as expected. When I run the .bat file though, it doesn't work.

I think the challenge comes from the fact that the bat script must move around directories, as the virtual environment must be created in a local folder, while the scripts and files it then calls are hosted in a network folder.

This setup can't change, so I instead need to be able to move around directories properly in my .bat file.

I've looked around in StackOverflow and couldn't find any questions relating to similar behaviour. I've been reading through the relevant documentation, but haven't found anything helpful yet. 
I'm running the anaconda3 distribution. Windows 10. 
I'm not sure what information might be helpful to troubleshoot, so please let me know if you need more information. You'll find my code below.

```
echo ON

REM Change directory to user's local dir
chdir C:\Users\USERNAME
C:

REM Check whether environments folder exists, if not, create it.
if not exist "C:\Users\USERNAME\Environments\" mkdir C:\Users\USERNAME\Environments

REM Create virtual environment in this new/existing folder and activate it.
python -m venv venv/
"./venv/Scripts/activate.bat"

REM Change directory to network drive where document files are located
chdir I:\NETWORKDIR_PATH\FOLDER_OF_INTEREST
I:

REM Make sure necessary packages are installed.
pip install -r ./src/requirements.txt

REM Run script and close shell after 20 secs
python "./src/main_script.py"

REM FOLDER_OF_INTEREST contains the following items:
REM two excel files which will interact with the main_script.py script
REM a folder called "src" which has the packages to be installed within my environment
REM "src" also contains two python scripts. The first is the main_script.py, the other contains functions called by main_script.py
```

As it stands, when I run each line individually in the cmd window, everything works just fine.

If I try to run the .bat file instead, the code runs until

```
python -m venv venv/
"./venv/Scripts/activate.bat"
```

at this point, the cmd window exits and  and nothing else happens...

Any help/advice is appreciated!

PS: the `ping` commands are there because if not, the cmd window exits too quickly and I can't see what happened.

Comment: What's in `activate.bat`?

Comment: it's simply the file I need to run to activate the virtual environment for my python script.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure how I can be more informative. It is the typical ```activate.bat``` file used to activate a python environment. I can't copy paste the code inside it in this comment though as it is too many characters long.

Comment: Change `"./venv/Scripts/activate.bat"` by `call "./venv/Scripts/activate.bat"`

Comment: THANK YOU!!! this did it. I'll try and read up on the difference "call" makes and why. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We think that the line ./venv/Scripts/activate.bat activates a virtual
>   environment in a shell different than where the rest of the code runs.

No. Batch files are executed line by line until it hits an `EOF` (End Of File). So at the end of `activate.bat`, the interpreter considers its job done and that's it.

To be able to "return" to the calling script, you need to [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) the called script (which basically saves a return point)

To literally start a script in another `cmd` instance (what you called "a virtual environment in a shell"), you'd need the [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command.